# How do i place hover button in table cell?

Tags: html, css, hover, cell

Im new to css/html but typing my best. Hope you can solution my html problem which is taken me forever now with no solution in sight. I'm try to place a CSS crossfade hover button into a table, so i can position it via CSS. I would be very grateful if anyone could share a suggestion or example. I will add the code below for you to check out. Thx Stewart

```css
body {
    background-color: #575757;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #AEAEAE;
}
    #table {
    position: fixed;
    top: 15px;
    left: 15px;
}
    /*......... crossfade on hover .........*/

    #hover img{
    -o-transition:.3s;
    -ms-transition:.3s;
    -moz-transition:.3s;
    -webkit-transition:.3s;
    position:absolute;
}
    .nohover{
    opacity:0;
}
    a:hover .hover{
    opacity:0;
}
    a:hover .nohover{
    opacity:1;
}
    /*......... crossfade on hover .........*/
```

```html
</style>
</head>

<body>

<div id="table"><table border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td width="250" height="60"><div style="position:fixed">
<a id="hover" href="index.htm">
<img src="http://wizzfree.com/pix/button2.png" width="250" height="60" class="nohover">
<img src="http://wizzfree.com/pix/button.png" width="250" height="60" class="hover">
</a>
</div></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you describe what's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

```css
body {
    background-color: #575757;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #AEAEAE;
}
    #table {
    position: fixed;
    top: 15px;
    left: 15px;
}
    /*......... crossfade on hover .........*/

    #hover img{
    -o-transition:.3s;
    -ms-transition:.3s;
    -moz-transition:.3s;
    -webkit-transition:.3s;
    position:absolute;
}
    .nohover{
    opacity:0;
}
    a:hover .hover{
    opacity:0;
}
    a:hover .nohover{
    opacity:1;
}
    /*......... crossfade on hover .........*/
```

```html
</style>
</head>

<body>

<div id="table"><table border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td width="250" height="60" style="position: relative;"><div style="position:absolute; top: 0; left:0;">
<a id="hover" href="index.htm">
<img src="http://wizzfree.com/pix/button2.png" width="250" height="60" class="nohover">
<img src="http://wizzfree.com/pix/button.png" width="250" height="60" class="hover">
</a>
</div></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thx george, that works fine. i really dont understand how you make it work! any change my code could be made shorter? i mean is my hover code full complex, do i need all the bits)

Comment: the only two changes that i made are:

1. I added this to the td element: style="position: relative;"
2. And this to the div element just inside of it (td) : style="position:absolute; top: 0; left:0;"

Answer (score 0):

So isntead of using images you should use button componenet. Whole part in anchor tag should be rewriten with somethink like this:

```css
button {
  border-radius: 50px;
  background-color: gray;
  color: black
}

button:hover {
    background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<!-- Instead of using <a> and images you should make button -->
<button>SomeButton</button>
```

Border radius will make your button roudned.

If you need detailed animations you should use css keyframes, tutorial and details you can find on [w3school](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp)